# How can I combine two android room Dao Query functions

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, androidx

I have a database where i can store some event `entities`. All of my `Dao` functions return some type of `LiveData` so i can get them in my repository and process them in background thread of my android app. So i have to get them in my `ViewModels` and finally observe them.
My event `entity` looks like this:

```
@Entity
data class Event @JvmOverloads constructor(@PrimaryKey val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
                 var title: String = "", var description: String = "",
                 var dateDate: Date = Date(), val date: String = DateFormat.format("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", dateDate).split(" ")[0],
                 val time: String = DateFormat.format("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", dateDate).split(" ")[1])
```

And my `Dao` looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM event WHERE id=(:id)")
    fun getEvent(id: UUID): LiveData<Event?>

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT date FROM event")
    fun getDates(): LiveData<List<String?>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM event WHERE date=(:date)")
    fun getEventsByDate(date: String): LiveData<List<Event?>>

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event WHERE date=(:date)")
    fun getEventsCount(date: String): LiveData<Int?>
```

Now because of my app structure i need to first in one of my fragments get all the events counts with a specific date so i can put the counts in `views` and in another fragment get the events list with the selected date from first fragment.
The problem is that i have to observe my `LiveData` so i can get to data types. and if im going to get the counts from my database i have to execute two Dao functions from my repository and then observe both data's at same time to get the needed outcome.(because the values depend on each other so i have to execute them together)
so i tried this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        dates = mutableListOf<DateForEvents>()
        datesString = listOf<String>()
        eventsListViewModel.datesLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {dates ->
            dates?.let {
                this.datesString = dates
                this.datesString.forEach {dateString ->
                    dateString?.let {
                        var dateCount: Int = 0
                        eventsListViewModel.getDatesCount(dateString!!).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { count ->
                            count?.let { countInt ->
                                println(countInt) // puts the right amount on console
                                dateCount = countInt
                                println(dateCount) // puts the right amount on console
                            }
                        })
                        println("dateCount $dateCount") // puts 0 no matter what
                        this.dates.add(DateForEvents(Date(it), dateCount))
                    }
                }
                recyclerView.adapter = DatesAdapter(this.dates)
            }
        })
    }
```

as shown after taking the list of so called `DateForEvents Objects` that will have a date parameter and events count i put these objects on my `RecyclerView` .
but the problem is that i can get the list of dates properly but i cannot extract the events count from my `LiveData`. when i get the count and put it in my temp variable the data is there but when i need to access after observing it is not the right value.
so i figured i have to combine the `getDates` and `getEventsCount` functions together so when i execute the combined function i can observe just one `LiveData` and extract the needed values. but i cant figure out how can i combine two queries or two functions together.
i hope that i could explain it good enough. every bit of help would be appreciated.